# Error in importing tensorflow probability

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

When I try to import tensorflow_probability, I get the following error report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    dir(globals()[pkg_name])  # Forces loading the package from its lazy loader.
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\lazy_loader.py", line 57, in __dir__
    module = self._load()
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\lazy_loader.py", line 40, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental import bayesopt
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\bayesopt\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental.bayesopt import acquisition
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\bayesopt\acquisition\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental.bayesopt.acquisition.acquisition_function import AcquisitionFunction
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\experimental\bayesopt\acquisition\acquisition_function.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal import prefer_static as ps
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\prefer_static.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend import numpy as nptf
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import bitwise
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\bitwise.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import _utils as utils
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.internal.backend.numpy import nest
  File "E:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\internal\backend\numpy\nest.py", line 73, in <module>
    assert_same_structure = dm_tree.assert_same_structure
AttributeError: module 'tree' has no attribute 'assert_same_structure'
```

I have tried to upload the following packages: tensorflow, tensorflow probability, tree. But I cannot fix the problem.

---

Here is the result of "pip3 list" in my computer.

absl-py     1.4.0

astunparse  1.6.3

cachetools  5.3.1

certifi     2023.5.7

charset-normalizer  3.1.0

click   8.1.3

cloudpickle     2.2.1

colorama    0.4.6

decorator   5.1.1

dm-tree     0.1.8

flatbuffers     23.5.26

gast    0.4.0

google-auth     2.20.0

google-auth-oauthlib    1.0.0

google-pasta    0.2.0

grpcio  1.54.2

h5py    3.9.0

idna    3.4

jax     0.4.12

keras   2.12.0

libclang    16.0.0

Markdown    3.4.3

MarkupSafe  2.1.3

ml-dtypes   0.2.0

numpy   1.23.5

oauthlib    3.2.2

opt-einsum  3.3.0

packaging   23.1

pandas  2.0.2

Pillow  9.5.0

pip     23.1.2

protobuf    4.23.3

pyasn1  0.5.0

pyasn1-modules  0.3.0

python-dateutil     2.8.2

pytz    2023.3

requests    2.31.0

requests-oauthlib   1.3.1

rsa     4.9

scipy   1.10.1

setuptools  65.5.0

six     1.16.0

svgwrite    1.4.3

tensorboard     2.12.3

tensorboard-data-server     0.7.1

tensorflow  2.12.0

tensorflow-estimator    2.12.0

tensorflow-intel    2.12.0

tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.31.0

tensorflow-probability  0.20.1

termcolor   2.3.0

Tree    0.2.4

typing_extensions   4.6.3

tzdata  2023.3

urllib3     1.26.16

Werkzeug    2.3.6

wheel   0.40.0

wrapt   1.14.1

---

Comment: Hi @Zhang Kongzheng, I am able to install tensorflow-probability in the given environment. Could you please try again installing tensorflow-probability module using the code - `!pip install tensorflow-probability`? Let us know if the issue still persists.